# Sombra interna do elemento pai sobre o filho

Tags: css, div, table, rolamento

Preciso fazer com que a sombra interna do elemento pai fique por cima do elemento filho. Tenho uma `div` com `overflow: scroll` e um `table` dentro dela que pode ser de tamanho maior que essa `div`. Estou fazendo com que apareça uma sombra interna nessa `div` em tal lado onde o conteúdo do `table` não aparece, para que o usuário saiba que pode rolar o `table`. O problema é que a sombra da `div` não fica sobre o `table`. Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom. Você não passou nenhum código, então eu criei esse rápido exemplo. Vê se resolve a sua situação.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  box-shadow: inset -30px -30px 30px 0px #000;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

### EDIT

Com cor e transparência:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  box-shadow: inset -30px -30px 30px 0px #000;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 151, 167, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
      <td>UIAHBUIABHAUIBAIUIABAUI</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Foi o que eu tinha feito. Porém, se a table tem background, as sombras não aparecem.

Comment: @MarlonLuís Entendi. Mas que tipo de fundo você está usando? Cor ou imagem? Poderia adicionar uma transparência ao fundo que ficaria legal, dependendo do seu caso?

Comment: A tabela tem um fundo com cor, mas não pode ser transparente. De qualquer forma, combinamos entre nós que deixaremos do jeito que está por outro motivo, mas caso alguém queira resolver o problema, isso ajudará outra pessoa. Obrigado!

Comment: @MarlonLuís Ok Marlon! Boa sorte aí!

Comment: @MarlonLuís Deixei um exemplo com transparência, caso te ajude em qualquer coisa.